# How To Set An Attribute Of A Web Component Dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, web-component

I am stuck on trying to set an attribute for a custom web component called `ws-dialog` I designed. It always adds an attribute `undefined` on the code:

```
<ws-dialog class="global" undefined="add-page-content"></ws-dialog>
```

What I want to do here is to declare an attribute like `template` instead of `undefined`. Here is the code that I used for adding an `onclick` event to all dialog target elements:

```
function addDialogEvents(target) {
    target.addEventListener("click", () => {
        let dialog = document.createElement(Dialog.getName());
        let body = document.querySelector("body");

        dialog.template = "add-page-content";

        body.append(dialog);
});
```

}

And here is the code for my custom component:

```
"use strict";


class Dialog extends HTMLElement {


    connectedCallback() {
        //Styles for this custom component are declared in a separate CSS module
    }


    updateContent(id) {
        let content = document.querySelector(`template#${id}`).content;

        if (content)
            this.append(content);
    }


    attributeChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) {
        this.TEMPLATE = "template";

        switch (name) {
            case this.TEMPLATE:
                this.updateContent(newValue);
                break;
        }
    }


    static get observedAttributes() {
        return [this.TEMPLATE];
    }


    static getName() {
        return "ws-dialog";
    }


    get template() {
        return this.getAttribute(this.TEMPLATE);
    }


    set template(template) {
        this.setAttribute(this.TEMPLATE, template);
    }

}



customElements.define(Dialog.getName(), Dialog);
```

Comment: add ``console.log("observed", this.TEMPLATE)`` statements to ``observedAttributes`` and all other methods so you learn **when** they run, and log what ``this.TEMPLATE`` is at that stage. This diaram helps as well: https://andyogo.github.io/custom-element-reactions-diagram/

Comment: I've tried the logging method and I found out that the `observedAttributes` gets called first when an attribute is set. So if I put the `this.TEMPLATE = "template";`, the property is set to `template`. But as soon as the setter method is called, it becomes `undefined` again. Does it have something to do with the fact that `observedAttributes` is `static`?

Comment: Edit your question and hit Ctrl-M (or the button) to insert a Code Snippet, paste your new code so we can execute it here on StackOverflow and see what happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a playground to help you see when what method is fired.

Note when **and how many times** `observedAttributes` is called.
That means your `this.TEMPLATE` is `undefined`, and thus becomes a String `undefined` in the Array

```html
<script>
  const log = (...args) => {
    let div=document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('DIV'));
    div.style = `background:${args.shift()};color:white;font:13px Arial`;
    div.append(args.join(" "));
  }
  customElements.define('my-element', class extends HTMLElement {
    log() {
      log(this.getAttribute("color"), this.outerHTML.split(">")[0],'>', ...arguments);
    }
    static get observedAttributes() {
      log('red', `my-element observedAttributes`);// NO 'this' / Element here!
      return ["color"];
    }
    constructor() { super().log("constructor") }
    connectedCallback() {
      this.log("connectedCallback" , this.innerHTML || "No innerHTML" );//FireFox difference!
      setTimeout(() => this.log(`delayed connectedCallback ${this.innerHTML}`), 0);
    }
    attributeChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) { // 4th W3C parameter = Namespace (not implemented in Browsers)
      this.log("attributeChangedCallback", name, oldValue || "null", newValue);
    }
    disconnectedCallback(){ this.log("disconnectedCallback") }
  })
  document.body.onload = () => {
    log('magenta', 'onload event');
    A.setAttribute("color", "darkolivegreen");
    B.innerHTML = "<my-element id=C color=hotpink>Charlie replaced Bravo</my-element>";
    B.remove();
  }
</script>
<my-element id=A color=green>Alfa</my-element>
<my-element id=B color=blue>Bravo</my-element>
```

Notes:

- Helpful diagram at: https://andyogo.github.io/custom-element-reactions-diagram/
- The execution order is slightly different in FireFox only, my advice is to not Develop, only Test in Firefox
- In FireFox you can access the inner Elements from the `connectedCallback`. In all other Browsers you need that `setTimeout`. Different tech interpretations of the same W3C standard. And in this case Apple engineers were correct [source](https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/issues/551). Chromium is based on the same engine.
- Note how (delayed) code from the **C** `connectedCallback` (or any method) runs **AFTER** the `disconnectedCallback`.
  You need to write code that does not error when DOM elements no longer exist.

---

**JSFiddle playground: https://jsfiddle.net/WebComponents/67pduja9/**

Comment: Thanks, I got it working and running earlier. The main problem was that a call from the HTML document happens when everything is loaded. Once a setter method was called, the value of `template' is 'undefined` again. I tried testing it with other codes, not web components, and I found out that you can't really define a `property` inside a `static` definition. The concept is quite similar to `Java`, which only allows declarations inside `constructors` and `object instances`. Anyway, I got it working by using `string` literals like `"template"`.